# How to only print next iteration of a permutation

Tags: python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

So basically I have a list of 26 objects (the letters of the alphabet)
I would like to be able to find what the next iteration of the permutation would be.

However to compute the entire permutation list and store this as a list to iterate through will take too much computational power as the total number of possible iterations is 403291461126605635584000000

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.permutations(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'], 26)))
```

For example.
If I had a small list of say 3 letters this would be much more straight forward.

```
import itertools
x = list(itertools.permutations(['a','b','c'], 3))
print(x[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

The method [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is a [`generator`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) function, which will create the next permutation when requested (calling `next()` on the `generator` object or iterating over it). All permutations will only be created in the case where you cast it to a `list` (which you are doing) or when you iterate over all of them.

```
from itertools import permutations

permutation_generator = permutations("ABCD", 2)

print(next(permutation_generator))
# Output: ('A', 'B')
print(next(permutation_generator))
# Output: ('A', 'C')
print(next(permutation_generator))
# Output: ('A', 'D')


# Example of iterating with a generator and stopping after two iterations
for i, permutation in enumerate(permutation_generator):
    if i > 1:
        break
    print(permutation)

# Output:
#   ('B', 'A')
#   ('B', 'C')

# Generating the next five permutations in a list
permutations_first_five = [next(permutation_generator) for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: Why not just call ```next()``` on the ```itertools.permutations``` object?

Comment: the for loop has to iterate through al permutations before giving a response . and does not work with permutations("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 26)

Comment: @Nin17 you're right, it is already a generator, which is not mentioned in the documentation. @formyzla you should calling `list()` on a `generator` object will generate all values, therefore you should only iterate over it or call `next()` on it.

Comment: If you're using itertools, there's no need for comprehensions or clunky for-loops: `list(itertools.islice(perm_gen, 5))`.